# Issues when mixing columns of type object and string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dtype

I stumbled on a quite surprising behaviour of pandas 1.4.2 when declaring columns with strings as `dtype('string')` instead of `dtype('O')`, which seems to be recommended by the pandas developers (see e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html).

See this simplified snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['a']=[1.0,2.0,3.0]
df['b']=list('abc')
df['c']=list('def')
df['cs'] = df['c'].astype('string')

p1 = df.pivot_table(index='b', columns='c', values='a')
p2 = df.pivot_table(index='b', columns='cs', values='a')

p1+p2 ### <- fails
```

The simple addition of 2 arrays of apparently the same shape ends with the following exception:

```
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice 
(START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, 
boolean array] types
```

The dtypes of the columns of p1 and p2 are respectively:

```
>>> p1.columns.dtype
dtype('O')

>>> p2.columns.dtype
string[python]
```

and that seems to cause the issue.

This is unfortunate, because if your code is mixing columns of dtype `dtype('O')` and `dtype('string')` you risk ending up with such unexpected errors.

I am wondering if anyone else found this issue, and what would be the recommended way to handle this.

Side note: when storing a dataframe with some index of dtype `string` and when rereading it, its "columns" index seems to have returned to `dtype('object')` status. E.g.:

```
>>> p2.columns.dtype
string[python]
>>> p2.to_hdf('data.h5','p2')
>>> p2b = pd.read_hdf('data.h5','p2')
>>> p2b.columns.dtype
dtype('O')
```

My take so far is to avoid casting columns of strings to dtype `string` at any cost. They still seem to behave better when declared as `dtype('O')`. The `dtype('string')` does not seem ready for daily use.

I am happy to receive any recommendations or suggestions.

Comment: Given that `StringDtype` is considered experimental, and this quote: "Currently, the performance of object dtype arrays of strings and arrays.StringArray are about the same. We expect future enhancements to significantly increase the performance and lower the memory overhead of StringArray." -- I guess my recommendation is... don't use it, or make sure your code is type safe?

Comment: @ddejohn I think I am going to follow your advice.

Comment: This question strikes me as opinion-based.

Comment: Granted, I find it odd that the Pandas developers suggest using an experimental feature that doesn't seem to provide any real benefits yet.

Comment: Note, if you convert all your string columns to `string` then things work as expected. It's only when there's mixed object/string dtypes that there's an issue.

Comment: @BeRT2me That's true in theory, but seems very cumbersome to sweep through my entire code base including branches in one go to do that. In addition, every time I store a dataframe to an HDF file, I will have additional housekeeping to recast the columns to string after reading them back.

Comment: @ddejohn I guess they did not detect that the new feature would have such side effects.